# Sql Server: Compact and LocalDB Denali

Tags: microsoft, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Does anyone knows the differences between these ones?

1. http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx (Look for CTP3 LocalDB in the page)
2. http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx

I wonder why microsoft started Denali project (now in CTP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my answer [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101041339/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx):

> LocalDB and SQL Server Compact?
>
> Small and simple database, lightweight
> installation, connecting to a database file -- this will sound
> familiar to any developer using SQL Server Compact. The similarities
> are not accidental, as our goal for LocalDB was to be as easy to use
> as SQL Server Compact (while being as powerful and compatible with
> full SQL Server as SQL Express).
>
> There are significant differences between LocalDB and SQL Server
> Compact:
>
> Execution mode: SQL Server Compact is an in-proc DLL, while LocalDB
> runs as a separate process.
>
> Disk usage: all SQL Server Compact
> binaries amount to some 4MBs, while LocalDB installation takes 140MBs.
>
> Features: SQL Server Compact offers core RDBMS functionality like
> querying, while LocalDB provides a much richer set of features,
> including Stored Procedures, Geometry and Geography data types, etc.

Comment: You beat me to it; I was just about to post a link to that page.

Comment: Are you AaronBertrand? If so, it's your merit: if you post it I will set that as answer.

Comment: haha no, I'm just a random dude named Aaron. Glad you found the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

A comparision between the different features of CE3.5, CE4, 2008 R2 Express and LocalDB (Denali CTP3) can be found here

http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

(yes a link - because it 's still a CTP)